# Stream desktop to website privately on wayland

Tags: fedora, wayland

I'm looking for a way I can create a web stream of my desktop so I can present it to coworkers during calls. Microsoft teams crashes when attempting to stream which I assume is because it hasn't been updated to support wayland.

I assume a solution would involve OBS piped in to some web service but I am not aware of any way I can do this without creating a public broadcast. I am able to port forward on this network so if needed I could run a local service and send a direct link.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could use `vlc`'s desktop streaming feature.